# compare column value with current date-Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

In google sheet I want to compare Column value(f12) with the current date, if its > Current date then show a tag as "a" else "b"

```
=IF(DAYS360(NOW,C20)<0,"A","b")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(Now()<A1,"A", "B")
```

this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y7H9SI1hbEW9RhLmSQ1JREsI3uBRetG_V_LR7l1DNcw/edit?usp=sharing